# ssh: authenticate only with rsa key

Tags: ssh, authentication, rsa

I am setting up ssh from OS X to a Ubuntu virtual machine (Virtual Box). I tried to set up key-based authentication, following the instructions [here](http://smbjorklund.no/ssh-login-without-password-using-os-x).

Now there is a problem. When my VM server is up running, and I am actually logged in at the server side, I can ssh without authentication. But when I log out at the server side (while the VM is still up), I cannot proceed without authentication:

```
no such identity: /Users/USER/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
no such identity: /Users/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
USER@192.168.56.10's password:
```

I can enter the password and log in without problem.

So, how can I change the configuration so that key authentication also works when I'm not logged in at the server side? From the message, there is no `id_dsa`. What I actually have in `~/.ssh` is `id_rsa`, so what's their difference?

Comment: Did you set up home directory encryption?  If yes, that would be your problem.  Your home directory doesn't get decrypted until after you are logged in.

Comment: @Zoredache  
Oh shoot... Exactly... So is there any way to stop encryption of home directory?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption  Make backups before you make any major changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't have to stop your encryption, you can move the authorized_keys file to another directory like an /etc/ssh/$USER

Comment: Well I've already removed the encryption... Thank you anyway. Your answer is rather interesting. Say I have moved the file to another directory like `/etc/ssh/$USER`, do I need to adjust configuration of the ssh server? If so, how? Since I've already removed the encryption I can't test it out.